# Grails error Unknown column 'projects0_.app_user_id' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, grails

I created some domain classes in Grails.

Project:

```
package localetool

class Project {
    String name
    Date createDate
    Date updateDate
    static belongsTo = [appUser: AppUser]
    //static belongsTo = AppUser   <- this works right
    static hasMany = [res: Res, books: Book]
    static mapping = {
        sort "updateDate"
    }    
    static constraints = {
        name unique: true, blank: false
    }
}
```

and AppUser:

```
package localetool
import com.kyt.auth.User


class AppUser {
    static hasMany = [projects: Project]
    User user

    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

This causes an error while starting app and use appUser.projects:

```
Unknown column 'projects0_.app_user_id' in 'field list'
```

When I use belongsTo without appUser, it works fine, but I want to have access to parent.

Comment: Make sure the tables are recreated when app is re-run. If it was run with initial approach then the FK would not have been there for Project table. Next try should drop and create the table with the FK column. Refer `DataSource.groovy`, `dbCreate = "create-drop"` should be used for concerned environment.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that grails update your db. Open it by some GUI client(like HeidiSQL for MySQL) and verify it

Comment: I had the same error. This made me realize that my app wasn't re-creating the tables properly. I shut down the app, did a database refresh (dropped & recreated all the tables), and got it to work. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem, a drop and create database and restart app solved the problem